# Buying glass panels for a shower frameless fixed panel setup: what specs should I be looking for the glass?

Tags: shower, glass

To eliminate doubts and a subjective question comments I would say that these are regular panels (say 36"x78") and the glass has to be clear finish.
I am being told that not all the glass is the same but when I ask for specs they are telling me "it is American regular clear 10mm think tempered glass"

Are there some specs or better glass that I could ask for or it is all the same ?

Comment: **Tempered** is really the only spec you need for glass shower panels. After that it's just what you want it to look like and how much you're willing to pay to make it look like that.

Comment: You really don't want plain glass near where you can slip and put your head though it.

Comment: I vaguely remember reading something about HD glass (very clear low iron) and some glass that is less favorable to droplets forming on the panel (fine surface, the water won't stay on it) but I can't find the references for the later. Don't care about the low iron/HD glass that is cosmetic for me. No droplets means low maintenance though

Comment: @crip659 definitely !

Comment: Low iron is mostly of actual use for solar panels - otherwise it's purely cosmetic (no greenish tint.)

Comment: well someone who wanted to charge me 3000CAD to supply and install those panels told me that "this is not glass made in China" so I have no idea what makes the other glass better